# How to sum @EditorFor in asp.net mvc with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm beginner and i'm trying to sum 2 fields @EditorFor (with AngularJS), what should I do?

This is what i have, but it doesn't work.

```
<div ng-app="">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity2, new { ng_model = "Quantity2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new {ng_model = "Quantity"})
<p>Sum: {{ Quantity ++ Quantity2 }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It should have only single `+` instead of `++` like `{{ Quantity + Quantity2 }}`

Comment: Doesn't matter. Still not working

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: Nothing. Btw. {{ 2 + 2 }} works, so angular works fine.

Comment: And what is the output if you have {{ Quantity ++ Quantity2 }}

Comment: nothing, just empty on view

Answer (score 0):

Now is fine...

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { ng_model = "Quantity" } })
```